# How are worldwide patent application numbers generated?

Tags: patentability, application, number, worldwide, help

If in a worldwide patent application I wanted to create a significant number (e.g. a spouse’s birthday/ wedding anniversary) would I be able to request that number or are the numbers randomly generated. I.e. If I would like my patent number to be WO2020051598A1 would this be possible?). Thank you for your time.

Comment: I can't be authoritative, but I believe the WO number is simply the year followed by a sequential number. Thus there is no way to get your desired number.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

It is sequential and there is no way to get a specific number.

Comment: Thanks for your time!